# javascript event OnKeyUp inside select/option element doesn't work at all

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Is it possible this, since when I try out it seems OnKeyUp event doesn't fire (in FF, IE) : 
This scenario is in static html and ajax also.

```
<select name=p_cat>
    <option value=1 onkeyup="script1(event,this)">Employee</option>
    <option value=2 onkeyup="script1(event,this)">Supervisor</option>
    <option value=3 onkeyup="script1(event,this)">Head</option>
    <option value=4 onkeyup="script1(event,this)">Manager</option>
    <option value=5 onkeyup="script1(event,this)">CEO</option>
</select>
```

My workaround is

```
<select name=p_cat onkeyup="script(event,this)">
    <option value=1>Employee</option>
    <option value=2>Supervisor</option>
    <option value=3>Head</option>
    <option value=4>Manager</option>
    <option value=5>CEO</option>
</select>
```

Is it correct to add onkeyup to option element (mouse events works)

thanks in advance

H Ivanov

Comment: The event listener is to be attached to the select element, not to the options.

Comment: I'm not sure this is even a question. The workaround is what you would do.

Comment: The interesting is that I check mouse events are firing well but these from the keyboard no. Is it an expected behaviour or kind of exception? My question is related suspicious for possible mistakes somewhere into the script. Thanks!

Comment: MelanciaUK, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I didn't understand you. Would you explain (you or who knows more) why it's not possible to use option keyboard events (again to remind - mouse events are working well)

Answer (score 1):

`<select name=p_cat onchange="script(event,this)">
    <option value=1>Employee</option>
    <option value=2>Supervisor</option>
    <option value=3>Head</option>
    <option value=4>Manager</option>
    <option value=5>CEO</option>
</select>`